# Cloud FireStore : NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index.?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firestore but gives me error.
I had two condition one condition is of userid and other condition is of get last 7 days data.

```
getReportData = (callBack) => {

var query = firestore().collection("booking")
query = query.where("docId", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
const currentTime = new Date();
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 8);

query = query.where("createdAt", ">=", d);

query.get().then((doc) => {
  const list = [];
  doc.forEach(function (docV) {
    list.push(docV.data());
  });
  console.log("data" , list);
  console.log("data length" , list.length);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log('booking error', error);

})
```

}

It gives me error

```
NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is said in the error, you need an index to execute this query.

Firebase helps a lot here, because it even provides you a link to directly create the index. You only have to follow the link to create the correct index and then your query will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to control panel in firebase and find index tab

[image: Firebase index panel]

but you not need to think about this, because the React Native Firebase when shows the error, he give a link like a:

`[firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project...`

When you click and open the panel the firebase will create a index for you.